# rosdep init error

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am installing ros from behind a proxy server
while using sudo rosdep init it gives a page address and then website may be down ,
while the proxy has been configured in apt.conf as well as exported using export command.

I checked using wget command, I am able to download the pages I enter the link for but when I enter the page address returned while using rosdep init it says proxy tunnelling failed.

What is the solution for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63485/rosdep-init-error/) by [anurag_meena](https://answers.ros.org/users/4973/anurag_meena/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Working behind a proxy is not currently supported. I opened a ticket https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/271 to add support for being behind a proxy.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1